# CRT displays for DEC PDP-8 series

Tags: hardware

Which types of CRT displays (if any) were in common use with PDP-8 series of computers? Which common ways were there to program a picture or text on those (vector, text-only, pixel-addressable types)?

I don't count here CRT teletypes (like ADM-3A) as "displays", since they are mostly irrelevant to the machine they are connected to.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not (historical) hardware tech support.

Comment: So I've changed it to be more programming-relevant

Comment: VT100 seems to be i8080-based, at least wikipedia says so.

Comment: This question only covers hardware capabilities, and is not a programming question in any way.  This is likely better suited for an answer at [Super User](http://superuser.com).  You can post there, but make sure to delete this question, so that your question is not cross-posted on both sites.

Comment: I'm not aware it ever supported CRTs, only current-loop terminals. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-8). Off topic.

Answer (score 1):

The PDP-8 could be coupled with various different vector graphic CRTs.  Absolutely not a VT100 at least during the days of the PDP-8 life time (1960s).  The VT100 did not exist prior to 1978.  It's precursor was the VT-52 and that didn't even exist at the time of the PDP-8 generation.  The VT-52 was more commonly used with the PDP-11 and the VT-100 made its appearance with the VAX-11/780.

I played Space-war on the PDP-8 CRT based system at Oregon State University in 1968.  I believe (not sure) that the CRT was interfaced to the PDP-8 along with using a vector graphics software package that seemed to float around from campus to campus in those days (before the days of uucp or Arpanet or Internet of course).